# Seleccionar el precio valor desde un array

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo el siguiente array de datos.

```
0   []
1   {…}
Precio  2171
Nombre  TNT
2   {…}
Precio  66500
Nombre  Externo
```

Este array  completa un select, pero deseo encontrar el precio mas bajo, que quede seleccionado y mostrar este precio en un `input`.

Mi function en JS

```
$.each(response, function(k, v) {
   if ($.isArray(response) || response.length) {
          $('<option>').val(v.Precio).text(v.Nombre).appendTo('#tipo_flete');
    }
});
```

Tambien la posibilidad que el array indice 0 no se agrege al select. Nose como validar eso.

Espero haberme explicado bien. Saludos.

Comment: @BetaM Primero declaro un array en vacio  `$data[] = array()` Despues lleno este array con un `array_push`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer algo así:

```
let minimo = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
let indice = 0;
$.each(response, function(k, v) {
   if ($.isArray(response) || response.length) {
          if (v.Precio < minimo) {
              minimo = v.Precio;
              indice = k;
          }
          $('<option>').val(v.Precio).text(v.Nombre).attr("id", "option_" + k).appendTo('#tipo_flete');
    }
    $("option#option_" + indice).prop('selected', true);

});
```

La idea es ponerle un id a cada  usando el indice del array, ir viendo cuál es el mínimo durante el loop, y guardar el indice del mínimo, para después poder encontrarlo y agregarle el selected.

Comment: Me muesta este error `TypeError: $(...).val(...).text(...).id is not a function`

Comment: Perdón, lo hice de memoria, ya edité el código.

Comment: Thanks my budda